# Vanilla Javascript equivalent for lodash _.includes

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm using the lodash `includes` function to check if a target value exists in an array...

```
_.includes(array, target)
```

and was hoping to find a good equivalent in ES5 (or ES6)

Did I miss something?  Is there no ES5 Array.prototype equivalent?

Or is my only option to use `indexOf`?

Comment: As you surmise, your best option in vanilla ES5 is `.indexOf()` as in `array.indexOf(target) !== -1`.

Comment: There is also [*Array.prototype.some*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some) if you want something a bit smarter than *indexOf* (also see [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)), so `array.some(function(o){return o === target})`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's _wrong_ with lodash `includes()`?

Comment: @AdamBoduch - No complaints about lodash. I love lodash. Just exploring the pain point for removing the dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ES2016:** [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(2);     // true
```

**ES5:** [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) `>= 0`

```
[2, 5, 9].indexOf(5) >= 0;   // true
[2, 5, 9].indexOf(7) >= 0;   // false
```

If you prefer a function:

```
function includes (array, element) { return array.indexOf(element) >= 0 }
```

and use it as:

```
includes([2, 5, 9], 5);    // true
```

Comment: thanks!  nice to know it'll be available in es7, and nice to learn about the tilde operator too!

Comment: So... word of caution. The 'tilde' operator is actually a bitwise _not_ operator. I would read up on it before you blindly use it. It is probably in your interest to just use `[2, 5, 9].indexOf(5) !== -1` or some variant of that, so that if/when another developer has to look at your code, he/she knows what is going on. You could just as easily wrap that in an includes method as well.

Comment: I agree with @kanzelm3, using `!== 1` much more clearly communicates the intent of the code. It will make your code much more readable, and therefor maintainable. If someone else who doesn't understand the `~` operator, or maybe even yourself after you've given yourself some time to forget about it, looks at this code later much time might be wasted trying to figure out what the code is supposed to do. Whereas a `!== -1` and a basic understanding of `indexOf` makes it very clear what the line does.  `!!~` might be useful for code golf, but otherwise I would stick with the clearer idiom.

Comment: Considering how weird that looks, it's better not to use it at all.

Comment: Agreed. ES5 version changed